# Multithreading/Concurrency issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I am writing a barbershop program using threads. Currently I have one barber and multiple customers coming in at the same time. However, after the first run through the program, the rest of the customers get all messed up. They all sit down at the same time. Is there something that I missed? My code is:

```
public synchronized void enter(Customer cust) {
    custList.add(cust);
       getCut(cust);
     }
      public synchronized void getCut(Customer cust) {    
    try {    
      notify(); 
      wait(); 


      System.out.println("sit down");
      notify();
      if (cashier==0) {
        cashier++;
        wait();
        System.out.println("waiting to pay");
        notify();     
        wait();
        System.out.println("left the room"); 
        chairs++; 
        cust.terminate(); 
      }



    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

  }
```

This is my barber part of it:

```
 public synchronized void cut(Barber barb) {

    cashier=0;

    try { 
     if(temp){
       System.out.println(temp);
        temp = false;
        notify();
        wait(); //wait for the customer to be settled in
        System.out.println("go to cus");
        notify(); 
        wait();


        System.out.println("cut cus hair");
        notify(); 

        wait();
        if (cashier==1) {

          System.out.println("got money");
          notify();
          cashier--;

          barbers++;

        }
     }      
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

  }
}
 public synchronized void goCut(Barber barb) {

cashier=0;

try { 
 if(temp){
   System.out.println(temp);
    temp = false;
    notify();
    wait(); 
    System.out.println("walks to cus");
    notify(); 
    wait();


    System.out.println("cut hair");
    notify()

    wait();
    if (cashier==1) {

      System.out.println("got the money");
      notify();
      cashier--;
      barbers++;

    }
 }
```

Comment: how about notify(); wait(); method

Comment: they are built into it. they switch back and forth between the synchronized threads..

Comment: Have you been able to get a more precise idea on where the issue is happening? It's kind of hard to go through all of the code, without easily spending a lot of time on it. Can you pin-point more precisely where the issue is coming from?

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with the locks. Is there a way to completely restart the barber thread after each customer?

Comment: Your wait & notify's are all over the place. It doesn't need to be that complex. BTW, are all these methods in the same class? Also, think about what each method is trying to do. Your method names are `goCut`, `cut`, `getCut` - all very (too?) similar.

Answer (score 0):

From the oracle site

> Note: Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true.

Please refer to [Guarded blocks multithreading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `notify` and `wait` randomly.

You have

```
notify();
wait();
```

at the beginning of the `getCut` method, what it does is:

- the first client comes in, it calls notify, and then waits
- the second client comes in, it calls notify - and thus it wakes the first client, and then it waits
- the third client comes in, it calls notify - in result the second client wakes up and so on

Instead you should thing of using notify and wake to block a particular resource (chair).

```
private final Object pChairLock = new Object();
private int pAvaliableChairs = 3;

...

// take the resource
synchronized(pChairLock)
{
    // wait until a chair is avaliable
    while(pAvaliableChairs == 0)
    { 
        pChairLock.wait();
    }

    // take sit
    pAvaliableChairs--;
}

// now the current thread 'is sitting'
//  - it can do some work using the resource

// after finishing, release the resource
synchronized(pChairLock)
{
    pAvaliableChairs--;

    // notify all waiting thread that resource is available
    pChairLock.notifyAll();
}
```

In this case you could just use notify(), but if different threads are waiting to release resource and to take it, then calling notify could wake a wrong thread.
Don't worry about waking too much thread at the same time, as each thread will check if the resource is available and only the first one will be able to take it - the rest will resume waiting.

This example uses three chairs, but you can use just one (boolean) or any other number. 
You can do the same with cashiers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below as a template (from Magee & Kramer's textbook)...

- ProducerConsumer = BarberShop
- create BarberShop with size of 1
- get = giveCut (barber "gets" a customer and gives customer a haircut)
- put = getCut (customer requests a haircut - i.e. "puts" a customer request for a haircut)

code:

```
public class ProducerConsumer {
  protected Object[] buf;
  protected int count = 0;
  protected int size;

  public ProducerConsumer(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    buf = new Object[size];
  }

  public synchronized void put(Object o) throws InterruptedException {
    while (count == size) wait();
    buf[count] = o;
    ++count;
    notifyAll();
  }

  public synchronized Object get() throws InterruptedException {
    while (count == 0) wait();
    --count;
    Object o = buf[count];
    buf[count] = null;
    notifyAll();
    return (o);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could handle the Barber (consumer) and Customer (producer) in several ways. For example, the Barber could be a thread that loops indefinitely simply giving haircuts (and would stop when the BarberShop closes). Or, the Barber could be spawned when one or more customers are waiting. You could create as many customer threads as you like.